# Discord bot not turning on

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots

Below is my code for a discord bot I am writing. I've written bots on discord in the past but its been a couple years and the api has changed a lot so Im just trying to get readjusted. Im currently hosting it on replit and working in their IDE. Whenever I click "Run" to turn the bot on, however, nothing happens. No console output, no nothing. The Run button says "Stop" for a second then goes back to Run. Anything Im missing/overlooked? Ive already tried changing to an older version of discord.js and it doesnt seem to help.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const TOKEN = process.env.TOKEN

const { Client, GatewayIntentBits } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
  ]
})

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}`)
})

client.login(TOKEN)
```

Comment: The code looks fine, could it be an issue with Repl.it?

Comment: For some reason, it seems as replit is fighting against discord applications, they take a decent amount of time to start up.

Answer (score 0):

Go in your replit shell and type
*kill1* and then enter.

after that run your code.
this will work.